# Who was/were the philosopher(s) that said "man is free when he feels like he is free"?

Tags: reference-request, freedom

I remember, some time ago, reading about a philosopher who said that a person is free if he feels like he is free (100% paraphrasing here). I can't seem to find who he/she was, any help?

Comment: I'm not certain if this is what you are looking for, but Camus describes an allegory of Sisyphus, who must perpetually push a boulder up a mountain. If he is happy in his efforts, he fights the very forces that put him there. Hume, also, stated something similar to what you mention, in reference to free will. Do you recall anything more about your reference?

Comment: @NationWidePants Thank you, but it wasn't Camus and I don't think it was Hume either. The philosopher was talking about freedom in a political sense, as in liberty. I think that his/her point was that, for example, even though you are restricted by laws and there may be things that are mandatory (i.e. you're not completely free), you can still be "free" if you feel like you are free. As opposed to someone in prison who probably doesn't feel like he's free.

Comment: kierkegaard, plato, john stuart mill?